# Set of Strings not holding data when called from another file

Tags: java, string, set, breadth-first-search

I have two class files, GraphBFS and FriendRec (which is an extension of GraphBFS). I have this method(getNodesAtDepth) within GraphBFS, included below, and one in FriendRec called getFriendRecommendations, also included below. When the list of nodes is created in getNodesAtDepth, it works as expected and includes all of the strings it should; however, when it is called in getFriendRecommendations, it is empty and has nothing there. Anyone have an idea what is going on?

```
public Set<String> getNodesAtDepth(int depths) {
    Set<String> ret = new HashSet<String>();        
    setInitialNode(initNode);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        String node = fetchFromQueue();
        setExploredNode(node);
        if(depths<depth.get(node)){
            break;
        }
        if(depth.get(node)==depths){
            ret.add(node);
        }
        Set<String> neighbors = graph.getNeighbors(node);
        for (String n : neighbors) {
            if (status.get(n) == null) {
                System.out.println("Node" + n);
                setFrontierNode(n);
                depth.put(n, (depth.get(node)+1));
                addToQueue(n);
                //ret.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Nodes at Depth Level" + depths + ":");
    System.out.println(ret.toString());

    return ret;
}

public List<Recommendation> getFriendRecommendationsInRankOrder(String node, int threshold) {
    List<Recommendation> recs = new ArrayList<Recommendation>();
    Set<String> friendsOfFriends = getNodesAtDepth(2);
    System.out.println("Geoffroy:" + getNodesAtDepth(2).toString());
    System.out.println("Blank Number" +friendsOfFriends.size());
    for (String n: friendsOfFriends){
        System.out.println("Support = "+getSupportFor(n));
        if(getSupportFor(n)>=threshold){
            System.out.println("BRANKKK");              
            Recommendation recTemp = new Recommendation(n,getSupportFor(n));
            recs.add(recTemp);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("t");
    // Now sort in reverse order of support
    Collections.sort(recs, Collections.reverseOrder());
    return recs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems while loop is not executing.

```
while (!queue.isEmpty())
```

what if the queue is empty ? Can you tell where that property is set ?